# Ruby on Rails error: "ArgumentError in PagesController#home" regarding cipher key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a rails application. I can't view it right now, my localhost:3000 is giving me an error.

Start Quote

ArgumentError in PagesController#home

Key must be 32 bites

Extracted source (around line #72):

```
cipher = new_cipher

cipher.encrypt

cipher.key = @secret

# Rely on OpenSSL for the initialization vector
iv = cipher.random_iv
```

End Quote

I honestly have no idea what any of this means. I can't find a PagesController, only a pages_controller. That file is only a couple lines and has no cipher in it. Is there a magic thing that I can do to fix this or is something deeper wrong?

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25185) out.

Comment: *I can't find a PagesController, only a pages_controller.*--In your rails project, there should be a file `app/controllers/pages_controller.rb`.  Inside that file, you should find the line: `class PagesController`.  And inside that class you should find the line:  `def home`.  That's where the error: `ArgumentError in PagesController#home` is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is about the ruby version, just for now if you want a quick solution use ruby 2.3.1